# How to get all consecutive subsets of a vector?

Tags: r, subset

If I want to get *all* subsets of a vector I can e.g. use the `sets` package:

```
library(sets)
v <- c("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4")
set_power(v)
## {{}, {"test1"}, {"test2"}, {"test3"}, {"test4"}, {"test1",
##  "test2"}, {"test1", "test3"}, {"test1", "test4"}, {"test2",
##  "test3"}, {"test2", "test4"}, {"test3", "test4"}, {"test1",
##  "test2", "test3"}, {"test1", "test2", "test4"}, {"test1",
##  "test3", "test4"}, {"test2", "test3", "test4"}, {"test1",
##  "test2", "test3", "test4"}}
```

**My question**
How do I get only all subsets, where *all the elements are consecutive*, so in the above case without `{"test1", "test3"}, {"test1", "test4"}, {"test2", "test4"}, {"test1", "test2", "test4"}, {"test1", "test3", "test4"}`

Comment: Why the downvote??? How can I improve the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `rollapply` like this:

```
library(zoo)
v <- c("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4")

L <- lapply(seq_along(v), rollapply, data = v, c)
L[[1]] <- matrix(L[[1]])
```

giving `length(v)` components, one for each subset size:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]   
[1,] "test1"
[2,] "test2"
[3,] "test3"
[4,] "test4"

[[2]]
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "test1" "test2"
[2,] "test2" "test3"
[3,] "test3" "test4"

[[3]]
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
[1,] "test1" "test2" "test3"
[2,] "test2" "test3" "test4"

[[4]]
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
[1,] "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4"
```

or as a flat list with one component per subset:

```
flat <- do.call("c", lapply(L, function(x) split(x, 1:nrow(x))))
```

giving:

```
> str(flat)
List of 10
 $ 1: chr "test1"
 $ 2: chr "test2"
 $ 3: chr "test3"
 $ 4: chr "test4"
 $ 1: chr [1:2] "test1" "test2"
 $ 2: chr [1:2] "test2" "test3"
 $ 3: chr [1:2] "test3" "test4"
 $ 1: chr [1:3] "test1" "test2" "test3"
 $ 2: chr [1:3] "test2" "test3" "test4"
 $ 1: chr [1:4] "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4"
```

Answer (score 9):

A `base R` option would be `embed`

```
lapply(seq_along(v), function(i) embed(v, i)[, i:1, drop = FALSE])
#[[1]]
#     [,1]   
#[1,] "test1"
#[2,] "test2"
#[3,] "test3"
#[4,] "test4"

#[[2]]
#     [,1]    [,2]   
#[1,] "test1" "test2"
#[2,] "test2" "test3"
#[3,] "test3" "test4"

#[[3]]
#     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
#[1,] "test1" "test2" "test3"
#[2,] "test2" "test3" "test4"

#[[4]]
#     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
#[1,] "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4"
```

Comment: Wow, never seen this function before! Brilliant, thank you.

Comment: Did some simple tests: yours is at least five times faster than G. Grothendieck's solution

Comment: ...on the other hand a vector of length 2000 crashes my system altogether while I still get a result with Grothendieck's solution. Any idea why?

Comment: @vonjd  Could be memory related.